# NRefactory AST Visitor, no visit method for certain nodes?

Tags: c#, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

We're currently working with NRefactory in a school project, and we noticed some nodes in the AST generated by the demo that we couldn't find a corresponding visit method to. For example:

```
ArrayCreateExpression
--Stuff with visit methods
--IsImplicitlyTyped = true
```

The node in question is `IsImplicityTyped`. Our question is, will the `IsImplicitlyTyped` node be visited? If so, by what? If not, where is it, assuming we're in the `VisitArrayCreateExpression` method?

EDIT: The sample code being parsed.

```
using System;

class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        int[] arr = new int[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also put code your parsing into the question.

Answer (score 2):

`IsImplicitlyTyped` is not a node, it's just a boolean property on the `ArrayCreateExpression`.

`IsImplicitlyTyped` will return true whenever `ArrayCreateExpression.CreateType` is the null node.